# Import Product from other stores

Tags: magento-1.9, importexport

I have 2 different websites A and B.

Now I want to show some product from B to A.

Which means, some Product in A website will be the same as in B website. Now I want to import these products from B website to A website.

How I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can go through `Admin -> Catalog -> Manage products grid` and search by website B in grid.

It will list all the products assigned to website B.

Now you can select products you want to assign to website A. And select update attribute options from action dropdown on top right of grid.

You can go through last tab websites and assign products to both websites A and B. See screenshot.

[image]

Comment: acually i am talking about 2 different webistes

Comment: Ohh I misunderstood that.. both websites are in magento?

Comment: yup on magento both sites

Comment: You will need to create feed for it. You can export products from site B and create feed for site A.

Comment: i will write script and get product of b now how i import product in A

Comment: Why do you want to write script. You can export all products from admin from site B